# Python: Adding a word from a stringlist to another stringlist

Tags: python, string, addition

I'm trying to add whole words from one string to another if they contain a certain character:

```
mylist = ["hahah", "hen","cool", "breaker", "when"]
newlist = []

for word in mylist:
    store = word          #stores current string
    if 'h' in word:      #splits string into characters and searches for 'h'
        newlist += store #adds whole string to list


print newlist
```

the result I expect is:

```
newlist = ["hahah","hen","when"]
```

but instead I'm getting:

```
newlist =  ['h', 'a', 'h', 'a', 'h', 'h', 'e', 'n', 'w', 'h', 'e', 'n']
```

How do I get my expected result?

Comment: why store = `word` ? just use word in code if you are not changing it.

Comment: I thought that if I didn't,`word` would be updated into a character list when it was being checked for 'h'

Comment: no it wouldn't. `in` just iterates on that, without changing it.

Comment: python's too smart for it's own good.

Comment: The comment `splits string into characters and searches for 'h'` is conceptually wrong. It checks whether the string contains 'h' as a substring, and does not modify the string in any way. In fact, it is **impossible** to modify a string in Python. You can only cause a variable to hold **another** string that represents a modified version of the original.

Comment: strings are immutable... my jedi master agrees

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`append` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
newlist.append(store)
```

Or shorter (using [*list comprehension* <sup>[docs]</sup>](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)):

```
newlist = [word for word in mylist if 'h' in word]
```

---

*Why does `newlist += store` not work?*

This is the same as `newlist = newlist + store` and is *extending* the existing list (on left side) by all the items in the [*sequence* <sup>[docs]</sup>](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) on the right side. If you follow the documentation, you will find this:

> `s + t`    the concatenation of `s` and `t`

In Python, not only lists are sequences, but strings are too (a sequence of characters). That means every item of the sequence (→ every character) is appended to the list.

Comment: Awesome. Further proof that Python is one of the most weirdest and most brilliant languages out there.

Comment: Please, just use the list comprehension. Premature optimization is premature, and the best approach may differ depending on the number/size of strings anyway. Besides, it's way more Pythonic. Stop trying to tell Python how to do things and just ask it to give you what you want. It's 2011. We have high-level languages that work well now.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel, @eryksun - according to ``timeit`` the list comprehension is the fastest (on my computer anyway). I've put my code and the results in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Out of interest I decided to see which of the three solutions (the loop, the list comprehension and the `filter()` function) was the quickest. My test code and the results are below for anybody else who is interested.

## Initialisation

```
>>> import timeit
>>> num_runs = 100000
>>> setup_statement = 'mylist = ["hahah", "hen","cool", "breaker", "when"]'
```

## Loop

```
>>> loop_statement = """
newlist = []
for word in mylist:
    if 'h' in word:
        newlist.append(word)"""
>>> timeit.timeit(loop_statement, setup_statement, number=num_runs) / num_runs
4.3187308311462406e-06
```

## List comprehension

```
>>> list_statement = "newlist = [word for word in mylist if 'h' in word]"
>>> timeit.timeit(list_statement, setup_statement, number=num_runs) / num_runs
2.9228806495666502e-06
```

## Filter call

```
>>> filter_statement = """
filt = lambda x: "h" in x
newlist = filter(filt, mylist)"""
>>> timeit.timeit(filter_statement, setup_statement, number=num_runs) / num_runs
7.2317290306091313e-06
```

## Results

1. List comprehension at 2.92us
2. Loop at 4.32us (48% slower than the list comprehension)
3. Filter call at 7.23us (148% slower than the list comprehension)

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
newlist.append(store)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternate syntax for expressing this is to use `filter`. Thus, an implementation for your problem would look something like

```
filt = lambda x: 'h' in x
newlist1 = filter(filt, mylist)
```

Comment: Note that this works, but using ``timeit`` shows it to be approximately 2.5 times slower than the list comprehension in Felix Kling's answer.